# localhost is not working in wamp server

Tags: localhost, wampserver

My localhost is not working, But when I type 127.0.1.1 on browser its working. When I run localhost, I get following thing[image: localhost]

Please advice me how to solve this.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What you expected to get?

Comment: When I run localhost what I got is the image above..  I am not able to run any of my project.

Comment: What you get when you ping localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you have not editied your HOSTS file properly.

Edit `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

You should have at least these lines in there, UNCOMMENTED i.e. without a `#` in column 1

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
::1        localhost
```

It is these lines that create the domain name localhost

Once the file is edited and saved either restart Windows or use these commands from a windows command windows started using "Run as Administrator"

```
net stop dnscache
net start dnscahce
```

---

**HOW TO EDIT THE HOSTS FILE**

*The hosts file is protected by windows, in order to save it you must have Administrator privilages.
Vista/W7/W8 you may think you are an Administrator BUT YOU ARE NOT.
To successfully save the hosts file do this to launch your editor with Admin Privileges.*

L*ocate your editors icon on the desktop or from the Start menus ( notepad will do if you have nothing else )
right click + shift  over your chosen editor icon - will show a menu.
select "Run As Administrator" from the menu.
Navigate your editor to the c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file.
When you have made changes you will now be allowed to save them.*